# How to fill particular areas in texture paint?

Tags: uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I tried to Google this for hours but couldn't find how to do this. I have an object with a texture that has a completely closed black circle. See this example: [image]

What happens it that if I try to fill my inner circle with orange, the whole circle fills. I wanted fill only the inner circle (similar colors). I was hoping if someone could tell how to accomplish this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the UV Image Editor Fill tool and play with the threshhold settings to see how well the fill works without spilling into the area around the colored area.[image][image][image]

Comment: Thanks. But what if your UV map lies outside of the closed loop? I forgot to add to the question, sorry. Like this: https://imgur.com/a/Yn5T5Db

Comment: You can paint a new boundary in the UV Image Editor to close that area - and then drop the fill into that enclosed space. BUT if you really want a lot of really good control, please look into using the Mask Tool in the 3d viewport - you can literally paint masks as if they are photoshop layer masks to isolate areas in the 3d view without having to paint directly on your color map.

Comment: I opted for closing the loop in the UV image editor, thanks!